# MVC 5 - How to convert hash password to readable text

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

MVC 5  >> convert hash password  to readable text.

Sample : HashPasword = AMVicVYXq/Gnj+gJ9QMThNZt84TJZwCIIUdFA3upr+wyMZUu4maPpkXiJhbZ5djwgw==
     should be convert to 123456

Comment: One does not simply walk into Mordor!

Answer (score 4):

By definition, a hash cannot be converted to readable text. So no, what you're asking is not possible.

`123456` might convert to `AMVicVYXq/Gnj+gJ9QMThNZt84TJZwCIIUdFA3upr+wyMZUu4maPpkXiJhbZ5djwgw==`, but `AMVicVYXq/Gnj+gJ9QMThNZt84TJZwCIIUdFA3upr+wyMZUu4maPpkXiJhbZ5djwgw==` will not convert back to `123456`.

Comment: Sure it can `HashPassword = "Hello World"` - now your hash variable is equal to the readable text "Hello World"

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum are you fighting in a who's-the-most-pedantic-person competition? Because you're winning!

Comment: If we're going for "most pedantic", technically it *could* be reversed if you knew the IV and key used to generate it, but since one or both of those is always random, and not stored, there's no way just with the string itself to get the original text back.

Comment: Why not, we can brute force ofcourse...

Comment: `technically it could be reversed if you knew the IV and key used to generate it` incorrect. Hashes aren't random. Same input is meant to give same output. One-directional, however.